# Symfony2: Check the checkboxes in a form

Tags: database, symfony, checkbox, entity

I have 3 entity: Person, Affiliation and PersonAffiliation.
The person can be edited with the possibility to add or delete affiliatons.

In my view, I should have a checkbox for every existing affiliation and the checkbox shuld be checked if the person has allready this affiliation.

I know how to display all affiliations in the view (twig) but I don't know how to check the checkboxes if the person has allready this affiliation.

Here is how the two tables looks like:

```
Person
    id
    firstname
    lastname
    ...
    affiliations

Affiliation
    id
    affiliation

PersonAffiliation
    id
    person_id
    affiliation_id
```

Now, my question is: Is there a possibility to use the controller and the view (twig) for doing this or the only possibility is to use Javascript (with JQuery)?

Comment: how about adding a function to the person like `public function hasAffiliation($affiliation)` and then in twig when looping through the affiliations, just call `{% if person.hasAffiliation(affiliation) }%....`

Comment: @mogoman, thank you for your reply. I had that idea but the problem I encountered is that in the twig, I have {% for aff in form.affiliations %} so the affiliaations are a form object and I don't know how and if it is possible to get the string or the affiliation object from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a proxy class, arrange your objects like this:

```
Person
    id
    ... as before
Affiliation
    id
    .. as before
-- remove PersonAffiliation --
```

but add this relation to your Person class

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Affiliation")
 * @JoinTable(name="person_affiliation",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="affiliation_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

You could do it all in the form builder like this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('person')
        ->add(
            'affiliation',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class'         => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Affiliation',
                'query_builder' => function($em) { return $em->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC'); },
                'property'    => 'affiliation',
                'multiple'    => true,
                'expanded'    => true,
                'required'    => false
            )
        );
```

And then just render your form with

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mogoman, but how to check those checkboxes now?

Comment: ah - I understand the problem. Is there a reason why you have the "proxy" entity (PersonAffiliation) and not using a manytomany unidirectional relation (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). The form will then work without problems.

Comment: In fact, my database is created like that, but  do you think that I can use manytoMany and negligate the proxy table PersonAffiliation ?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this immediately, but something I don't understand, how can I check then if the corresponding affiliation should be checked? And also how to check the box?

Comment: I sow the possibility to get the value of the twig form objec, for example I have affiliations and a for loop, then inside I can do aff.vars.value but I am geting only ints (1,2,3 etc.). If I could get the object affiliation from there...

Comment: I believe the object isn't saved there because you run `form->createView` in the controller. What you could do is (in your controller) make an indexed affiliation list `$affliations[$aff1->id] = $affiliation` etc - then in twig `{{ affiliations[aff.vars.value] }}`

Comment: Great idea.. Do you maybe know how to get all the affiliations from the Affiliation table (with EntityManager).

Comment: do you mean `$entities = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Affiliation')->findAll();` ?

Comment: I have it, it's getAll(). But another problem now... The "aff.vars.value" returns me 1,2,3, that's not the id's of the affiliations, it's the first, the second and the 3rd affiliation

Comment: what about this. In your person class make a method `public function checkAffiliation($id) return true/false` then in twig `{% if person.checkAffiliation(aff.vars.value) %}CHECKED{% endif %}`

Comment: The problem is that aff.vars.value is returning me 1 for the first aff, 2 for the 2nd one, 3 for the third one etc. This is not the id of the aff...

Comment: It might be aff.vars.value.id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19291/discussion-between-mogoman-and-milos)